Print loop content in an R Markdown report without changing text format
I am preparing a dynamic R Markdown report that requires printing R objects.
First, I define the objects:
{r setup, echo=FALSE}
number <- 25
numbers <- 1:5

And then I print them as follows:
r sprintf("Here I want to print the number %i", number)

However, at some points of the report I also need to include loops within the R code.
In those cases, I have tried to use:
{r echo = FALSE, comment = NA}
for (i in 1:5) {
  sprintf("Here I want to print the number %i", numbers[i])
}

but the sprintf() function does not print the content included within the loop.
Instead, I've tried with cat(sprintf()) as follows:
{r echo = FALSE, comment = NA}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat(sprintf("Here I want to print the number %i\n", numbers[i]))
}

which prints the content, but as you can see, it uses a different text format, which makes the report quite ugly.
Is there any way to correct this and obtain the same text format as in the first example using r sprintf("...")?

The for loop is probably your issue, not sprintf…

You are almost there. Knitr outputs text - per default - as verbatim text (and in fenced blocks). What you want is output to be treated as (raw) markdown content.
For this, put the r chunk option to result="asis". This will do the trick.
P.S. Move the newline to the beginning to make it work.
The following chunk starts with {r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat(sprintf("\nHere I want to print the number %i", numbers[i]))
}


